# How to pass a variable from a class to another?

Tags: ios, swift

I need my app to pass the value of a variable `myVariable` from a class `firstClass` to another `secondClass` only when the variable changed its value. To do so, I thought of using the `willSet` property. Though, in Swift, you can't use it after the declaration of the variable.

```
class firstClass: NSObject {
    var myVariable = 0

    func myFunction {
       myVariable = 5
    }
}

class secondClass: NSObject {
    var otherClass = firstClass()
    // How do I retrive the value of the variable right after its value changed?
}
```

I also thought of adding a `NSNotification`, but that wouldn't help because it doesn't pass a value. `NSNotification` only alerts about its changes.

```
 let myVariableNotification = NSNotification(name: "myVariableNotification", object: nil)

 class firstClass: NSObject {
    var myVariable = 0

    func myFunction {
       myVariable = 5 
       notificationCenter.postNotification(myVariableNotification)
    }
}

class secondClass: NSObject {
    var otherClass = firstClass()
       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("myVariableNotification", 
         object: nil, 
         queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
         usingBlock: { notification in
         println("The variable has been updated!")
       })
}
```

I seem to find no way to pass a variable once that variable changed its value. How can I do that?

Comment: You want to pass value when navigating from 1st viewcontroller to 2nd or only when there is a change in value of that variable?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Only when `myVariable` changed its value. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use delegate protocols. For more information check out [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) document.

Set up a `protocol` in the `secondClass`, right after the `import` statements, like so:

```
protocol InformingDelegate {
    func valueChanged() -> CGFloat
}
```

Inside the same `secondClass` create a `delegate` variable (some suggest that it should be marked as `weak`):

```
var delegate: InformingDelegate?
```

Then, create some method in which you will access the changed value. You can assign it to `value` for example:

```
func callFromOtherClass() {
    value = self.delegate?.valueChanged()
}
```

This is it for the `secondClass`. Now onto the `firstClass`.
Here you only need to conform to the protocol by adding `InformingDelegate` after the class definition, like this:

```
class firstClass: UIViewController, InformingDelegate {
    ...
}
```

Then, inform the compiler that you are going to be a delegate for the other class by creating its instance, and setting yourself to be the delegate:

```
var secondVC : secondClass = secondClass()
secondClass.delegate = self
secondClass.callFromOtherClass() // This will call the method in the secondClass  
// which will then ask its delegate to trigger a method valueChanged() -   
// Who is the delegate? Well, your firstClass, so you better implement  
// this method!
```

The last thing is to actually conform to the protocol by implementing its method:

```
func valueChanged() -> CGFloat {
    return myVariable // which is 5 in your case (value taken from a question)
}
```

This will assign `myVariable` value (5 in this example) to the `value` in the other class.

Comment: Thank you very much! Should I put `var delegate: InformingDelegate?`  in the first or second class?

Comment: You create a protocol, and a var "delegate" in the class that will retrieve the value. Then you set the other class (the one which will implement the method and set the value) as a delegate of this protocol by assing InformingDelegate to the class definition.

Comment: Thanks! Where should `protocols` be put in? Outside the class?

Comment: protocol definition should be put above the class definition, right after import statements :)

Comment: Working on it right now. I can't thank you enough for the effort you put in writing this :-) Thanks!

Comment: Delegates are not the easiest to understand, but after you get the idea, you'll find that you can use them in multiple situations and the time you put into learning them is definitely worth it.

Comment: @Fengson you rock!  thanks for the effort to write this mini-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Best way to program this would be using NSNotification. Add a observer in your 2nd viewcontroller to listen for change in value of this variable. In 1st viewcontroller whenever this variable changes value post a notification to observer which 2nd viewcontroller is listening to.

You'll have to use the "userInfo" variant and pass a NSDictionary object that contains the value of myVariable:

```
NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"myVariable": @(myVariable)};
NSNotificationCenter *notifying = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[notifying postNotificationName:@"myVariableNotification" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
```

In your second viewcontroler which calls your notification center method
set the notification and its calling method as below:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeInValue:) name:@"myVariableNotification" object:nil];
```

Calling method:

```
-(void) changeInValue:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"myVariableNotification"])
        {
            NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
            NSNumber* myVariable = (NSNumber*)userInfo[@"myVariable"];
            NSLog (@"Successfully received test notification! %i", myVariable.intValue);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does `NSNotification` pass a value? I used it but it only alerts about the changes of a variable. Please check my edited question. I added the code I'm using to declare and set up a `NSNotification`. Could you please show some code? Thanks!

Comment: Will that variable always be integer returning?